# In how many ways can they form a committee of 6 members that does not include both Chloe and George?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

The Data Science Club has 18 members, including Chloe and George who are currently not in good terms. In how many ways can they form a committee of 6 members that does not include both Chloe and George? (Note: Either Chloe or George can be on the committee but not both of them.)

Comment: **Hint:** How many ways if you don't care?  How many of those ways were "bad" because they were both on the committee?  How many ways are "good" then?

Comment: i tried doing 18C6-18C4 but the answer is wrong.

Comment: If chloe and george are both on the committee... then we have two of our six members already chosen.  We need four more people to choose.  How many people do we choose them from?  Again... chloe and george have already been chosen *and they can't be chosen again*.

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven’t figured it out yet, it’s ${18\choose 6}-{2\choose2}{16\choose4}= {18\choose 6}-{16\choose4} $. There are only 16 people to choose from after forcing Chloe and George to be in the group. That is, you subtract the number of groups with Chloe and George (the undesired groups) from the total number of possible groups to get the number of groups that are permissible.

Comment: the answer is wrong that way because the question says either Chloe or George can be in the group. One of them can be in the group. if Chloe in group, then Goerge not present. If George present in the group, Chloe is not. I am struggling to do it. Thanks for the response

Comment: Are you saying you have the answer and this is wrong? This answer is supposed to allow for groups that include only George but not Chloe, only Chloe but not George, or neither George nor Chloe

Comment: @bonny this answer is correct.  This is a very standard exercise and this is a very standard solution.  The solution can be written in different ways of course but it will equal the same final result.  You say "*the answer is wrong that way*" implying you have available what you think is the correct answer.  Share what it is and we will tell you why it is wrong or why it is the same answer as this.

Comment: One of those other ways it could have been written is as the groups who have neither, plus the groups who have chloe but not george, plus the groups who have george but not chloe.  That gives an answer of $\binom{16}{6}+\binom{16}{5}+\binom{16}{5}$ or similar... which of course equals the same as what is given above (*seen either by direct computation and comparison or seen by rearrangement of [vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)*).  It is often far less arithmetic to approach as above by subtracting the "bad" cases from the total overall count.